# Spheroidal Harmonics

Tags: special-functions

There is a (scalar) field `P` varying on a spheroid (squashed) surface. This field is a function of four independent components `(t,r,theta,phi)` as `P[t,r,theta,phi]`. I want to decompose `P` on this spheroid surface as follows

```
P[t,r,theta,phi]=Exp[-i*k*t]R[r]Exp[i*m*phi]S[theta]
```

thus I need to use Spheroidal Harmonics `S[theta]`. However, I realized there are different types of Spheroidal Harmonics in Mathematica Language. Can someone tell me how to expand `P` in Mathematica in the mentioned form?
Thanks all.

Comment: Can you, please, include some example definition of `P`, even if it is some toy example? Thanks! As it stands, it is unclear how this can be answered. Also, how exactly are `S` and `R` defined?

Comment: @CATrevillian Yes, of course. For example, on a spherical surface, we use `P[t,r,theta,phi]=Exp[-i*k*t]R[r]Y[theta,phi]` for decomposition so that `Y[theta,phi]` are spherical harmonics and `R(r)` is an arbitrary function of `r`. However, I do not know how to decompose the angular part on a spheroid. I mean, what is the suitable function in Mathematica which should be replaced instead of spherical harmonics? As an explicit example, please look at equation (14) of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269308007582)

Comment: @CATrevillian I know, I can define the spherical harmonics in Mathematica through `SphericalHarmonicY[l,m,\[Theta],\[Phi]]`. But I do not know how to define spheroidal harmonics.

Comment: Please, update your question with such information as it can easily be buried in the comments..